# How to retrieve all the keys from an ini file?

Tags: inno-setup, ini

I am creating an installer using inno setup and I am using a simple ini file as a database for a specific operation. My ini file consist of section users and key username and its value is the username of a particular person. Example:

```
[Users]

username=alice

username=bob etc....
```

In one of the custom pages created by me, I am prompting the user to enter the username, so now I need to check whether the entered username exists in the ini file or not.
So how can I achieve this.

Comment: can sum one help plz????

Comment: No one is hovering over the keyboard to reply to your posts immediately. Try having a bit more patiance rather than posting chasing after just 2 hours!

Answer (score 1):

As the duplicate value names are invalid in INI files, There are no API methods (Inno or not) to read them. You'll need to do it manually using Inno's [`LoadStringsFromFile()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile.htm). and check eahch line in turn.